# How do I prevent pasting into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am quite new to VBA, and I have encountered an odd issue with the following code snippet. My goal is to insert rows when a user pastes data manually into a table. The user copies a portion of the table manually (let's say column A1 through C25 -- leaving cloumns D and E untouched), and when pasting it manually into A26, the rows are inserted. This way, the table expands in order to properly fit the data (because there is more content under the table).

Now, the code shown below does sorta work, the only issue I am having is that the pasted data in columns (A through C) are repeated on all columns (D through F, G through I, etc..)

How do I prevent this pasted data from overwriting my other columns on the rows that I inserted (and from continuing "forever")

```
' When cells are pasted, insert # of rows to paste in
Dim lastAction As String
' If a Paste action was the last event in the Undo list
lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then
    ' Get the amount that was pasted (table didn't expand)
    numOfRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    ' Undo the paste, but keep what is in the clipboard
    Application.Undo
    ' Insert a row
    ActiveCell.offset(0).EntireRow.Insert
End If
```

The reason I am using the command bar's undo control is because this code needs to run on a manual paste event.

Comment: is this a `Table` defined as such in Excel? Or just a table of data?

Comment: It is just a table of data. Just cells with data in it - nothing special.

Comment: I am working on a solution - is this in the worksheet change event?

Comment: Yes, it is the worksheet change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. I removed the data from the clipboard, but stored it to a variable first so the rows could be inserted then the data added to the appropriate place, leaving other columns blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' If a Paste action was the last event in the Undo list
Dim lastAction As String
lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then

    Dim rng() As Variant
    rng() = Target

    numofRows = Target.Rows.Count 'get amount of rows pasted
    numofColumns = Target.Columns.Count 'get amount of columns pasted

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False 'stop events from firing momentarily
        .Undo 'undo paste action
        .CutCopyMode = False 'remove data from clipboard
    End With

    ActiveCell.Resize(numofRows, 1).EntireRow.Insert 'insert new amount of rows based on paste

    ActiveCell.Resize(numofRows, numofColumns).Value = rng() 'replace pasted values

    Application.EnableEvents = True 'turn back on event firing

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is really close to working properly. Currently, the "replace pasted values" does not replace what was pasted originally. Instead, it is pasting the data that used to be in the cells. In other words, it placed the amount of rows, but row 23's original data (which was part of the table underneath) was placed back. Could it be the "Remove data from clipboard"?

Comment: @BrettComardelle - I think it was actually the `Undo` command. It was resetting the value of the `Target` cells. I loaded into an variant array instead of a range and the new values stuck that way.